# The parity of the function $f(x)=x^{2^{x^2}}$?

Tags: functions, parity

Someone claims that $f(x)=x^{2^{x^2}}$ is an even function which I highly doubt.

I claim that $f(-0.5)=(-0.5)^{\sqrt[4]{2}}$ which is an imaginary number and $f(0.5)$ is a real number.

Can I have some confirmation regarding this?

Comment: Perhaps the intention of the claimant was to restrict $f(x)$ to the domain of integers?

Comment: Or was it $(x^2)^{x^2}$?

Comment: The person who claims this is trying to teach parity of functions using f(-x)=f(x).  So, naturally the domain would be real numbers since this is a precalc course.  Since I have not taken complex analysis, I was wondering if there is any reason why this function would be even in the complex plane.  As an integer, though, being even, is one of the reason why I can see that the teacher was confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the domain we're talking about. If we take it over the integers, then it actually *is* an even function; this follows from the fact that $2^{x^2}$ is an even number for any integer $x$ other than $0$. Moreover, since $2^{x^2}=2^{(-x)^2}$ and $x^{c}=(-x)^{c}$ for even $c$, we get the desired answer.

However, if we take it over the real numbers then, well, firstly, it's not quite clear that the function is well-defined (we have to be careful about exponentiation of negative numbers), but your objection certainly holds in that case.

Comment: That's what I thought.  Thank you.